# how to configuring vagrant to allow some specific IP to be available on a windows machine?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, vagrant

I have Vagrant installed on my windows machine. I am using putty to ssh to the ubuntu machine. Lets say that I need some specific service (let's say a graphite for stats) which should be reached with an IP address to access the GUI of that service. Is it possible to configure vagrant so that specific IP would be reachable through via browser on my windows machine?

Comment: Please have a look at http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask . At a minimum, state what you've tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify it in the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.17"

  # ...
end
```

See [the docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) for more information. Also note that you should use an IP address (of a [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)) which won't overlap with any other networks your computer is connected to.